# How do I build my application for the iPhone device (not sim)

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, sdk, certificate

I keep getting this error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I have paid me $99 (which I had to beg/borrow/steal).

Thanks

Comment: +1 for beg/borrow/steal although I hope you didn't actually steal! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install a provisioning profile which you can get at the iOS provisioning portal. Go to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), click iOS dev center, login, then iOS provisioning portal.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I create a CSR file (there was not any file in my key's directory under the keychain tool)

Answer (score 2):

in your project setting you need to define the provision profile in **Code signing** section inside that change the  **code signing identity** to your developer provision profile that you can download/create from developer.apple.com  instead of 'iPhone Developer'....

Comment: Mihir, how do you "define the provision profile"?  I dont see a tab for that.

Comment: Go to Project setting... in that go to the Code Signing section there you can change it... please refer this screen shot... http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/7065/screenshot20110209at115.png